# mule 4 batch job how to handle erroring records

Tags: mule4

I have an 34 MB XML file that I read and write to a DB table utilizing mule 4 batch module. I get a few errors from the operation. I am reading batches of 100 records and  when I commit to the DB table if one error occurs all 100 in the batch are dropped. Is that the usual behavior and is there a way to just only drop the erroring records. I am unable to catch the erroring records thru the error handler. Below is the flow.

```
    <flow name="-workday-outbound-investigator-job-history-int073Flow" doc:id="088c7b73-6d0a-4cbc-9ba4-94d149ae1e51" initialState="started" >
        <sftp:listener doc:name="On New or Updated File" config-ref="SFTP_Config" directory="${sftp.workingdirectory}" recursive="false" outputMimeType="application/xml" autoDelete="false"  >
            <scheduling-strategy >
                <cron expression="${cron.expression}" />
            </scheduling-strategy>
            <sftp:matcher filenamePattern="aaa_*.xml" />
        </sftp:listener>
                    <set-variable value="#[attributes.fileName]" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="3a2502e8-d1c4-4f0a-b1cd-1fcd17e7276c" variableName="file_name"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="5fd8692f-d4d1-4b00-8d6a-36a7981a55d0" >
                        <ee:message >
                            <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
import java!org::apache::commons::lang3::StringUtils
---
        payload.*Report_Data.*Report_Entry map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) ->{
            USERNAME: payload01.UserName default null,
            ACTION: payload01.Action default null,
            EFFDT: payload01.Effdt as Date { class : "java.sql.Date"} default null, 
            ACTION_REASON: payload01.ActionReason default null,
            DTTM_COMPLETE: StringUtils::replace(StringUtils::substring(payload01.DateTimeCompleted,0,19),'T',' ') default null      
        }]]></ee:set-payload>
                        </ee:message>
                    </ee:transform>     
        <batch:job jobName="-workday-outbound-investigator-job-history-int073Batch_Job" doc:id="c8683f42-0bb5-481c-890c-3b20f035c67d" maxFailedRecords="-1">
            <batch:process-records >
                <batch:step name="Batch_Step" doc:id="2fa9964f-ebcc-4588-8025-c36c74613521" acceptPolicy="ALL">

                    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="09298332-6541-47ee-8977-6a42c4ac0f89" message="BATCHINSERTSIZE #[sizeOf(payload)] "/>
                        
                    <batch:aggregator doc:name="Batch Aggregator" doc:id="f746013d-7c90-4d62-bbe0-02c306e22f3d" size="100">
                        <try doc:name="Try" doc:id="22c7241f-d136-40cc-95dd-ec51d6fcf6ec" >
                        <db:bulk-insert doc:name="Bulk insert" config-ref="Oracle_Wint_Database_Config" doc:id="cc38a9d1-3263-4cb2-bd7f-4d04558189eb">
                            <db:bulk-input-parameters><![CDATA[#[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
        payload map ( val , idx ) ->{
            USERNAME: val.USERNAME default null,
            ACTION: val.ACTION default null,
            EFFDT: val.EFFDT as Date { class : "java.sql.Date"} default null, 
            ACTION_REASON: val.ACTION_REASON default null,
            DTTM_COMPLETE: val.DTTM_COMPLETE default null       
        }]]]></db:bulk-input-parameters>
                        <db:sql><![CDATA[INSERT INTO
  WD_JOB_HISTORY (
    USERNAME, 
    ACTION, 
    EFFDT, 
    ACTION_REASON, 
    DTTM_COMPLETE 
  ) 
VALUES
  (
    :USERNAME, 
    :ACTION, 
    :EFFDT, 
    :ACTION_REASON, 
    :DTTM_COMPLETE 
  )]]></db:sql>
                        </db:bulk-insert>
                        </try>
                        
                    </batch:aggregator>                 
                </batch:step>
            </batch:process-records>
            <batch:on-complete >
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="41e67041-b38e-4ebb-afab-486b1927470b" message="JOBCOMPLETE"/>
                <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="48a4f377-14c2-47aa-bf54-c33d8402ec3f" >
                    <ee:message >
                        <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
 output application/json
 ---
 {
"Time [milliseconds]": payload.elapsedTimeInMillis as String default '',
"Total Records": payload.totalRecords,
"Successful Records": payload.successfulRecords,
"Failed Records": payload.failedRecords,
"Loaded Records": payload.loadedRecords,
"Processed Records": payload.processedRecords
 }
]]></ee:set-payload>
                    </ee:message>
                </ee:transform>

        <email:send config-ref="_Email_SMTP" fromAddress="${.mail.from}" subject="#['File completed ' ++ vars.file_name ++ ' in ' ++ dw::System::envVar('WRAPPER_HOSTNAME')]">
            <email:to-addresses >
                <email:to-address value="${.mail.to}" />
            </email:to-addresses>
            <email:body contentType="text/html" >
                
                        <email:content><![CDATA[#[%dw 2.0
import * from dw::System
output application/json
---
{
"job_stats" : payload,
"status" : "INT073 Investigator Job History completed",
"filename": vars.file_name
}]]]></email:content>               
            </email:body>
        </email:send>
                                
            </batch:on-complete>
        </batch:job>
        <error-handler >
            <on-error-continue enableNotifications="true" logException="true" doc:name="On Error Continue" doc:id="aed0a547-f56a-49a8-b448-113c2b944415" >
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Main Flow Error" doc:id="9fa9041d-fa2a-4c89-9312-4e25399c13f7" message="Error in Main Flow"/>
                    <email:send config-ref="_Email_SMTP" fromAddress="${.mail.from}" subject="#['File Errored out for Employee_ID ' ++ vars.file_name ++ ' in ' ++ dw::System::envVar('WRAPPER_HOSTNAME')]">
                    <email:to-addresses>
                        <email:to-address value="${.mail.to}" />
                    </email:to-addresses>
                    <email:body contentType="text/html">
                        <email:content><![CDATA[#[%dw 2.0
import * from dw::System
output application/json
---
{
"filename": vars.file_name,
"status" : "errored out",
"error_payload" : payload default ''
]]]></email:content>
                    </email:body>
                </email:send>               
            </on-error-continue>
        </error-handler>        
    </flow>
```

Comment: Note that you can use DataWeave built in features instead of Apache Commons StringUtils.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use an error handler in the flow to catch errors in a batch. That's expected because batch jobs execute asynchronously with respect to the flow. Think of it like the flow fires and forgets about the batch job execution, and just continues executing the next operation in the flow.

Batch implements some [specific error handling](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/batch-error-handling-faq) for cases like yours. If you want to send a message on failed records you just add a new batch step and set its `acceptPolicy` attribute to `ONLY_FAILURES`. Inside that step you can then take appropriate actions to report the errors. See [Batch Filters](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/batch-filters-and-batch-aggregator#batch-filters) for more details.

Example:

```
<batch:job jobName="batchJob">
    <batch:process-records >
        <batch:step name="batchStep1">
            ...
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step name="batchStep2" accept-policy="ONLY_FAILURES">
            ...
        </batch:step>
    </batch:process-records>
 </batch:job>
```

Comment: Thanks @aled. That worked. before I get into the batch step I needed to delete the database table  records. Before Mule 4 I was using wiretap to do that and worked well. So  I saved the file contents to a variable and did the db delete and then set the payload to the variable. before the batch processing. I was getting errors. Also the file is quite large . Is there a way to do this better.

Comment: Please open a new question for that and provide more details.